# Encrypted URL results in Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encryption

Before stating the problem I want to say that I've read all the posts that suggest that what I'm doing is a bad idea and I AGREE WITH YOU 100% but, our customer insists that he wants the id on the URL to be encrypted so we don't have much choice.

The application is ASP .Net MVC 2 and we are using the basic default route of 
"{controller}/{action}/{id}" in which the id is encrypted.

The code that returns the encrypted id is as follows:

```
return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Encryptor.Encrypt(inputText));
```

The Encrypt method is using the System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged class and we get something like:

*http://localhost:3396/MyController/MyAction/%253fval%253dWrikkm9UeEmHdsaMJyjgzA%253d%253d*

Now when I click on the link I always get a blank page saying:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request.

I guess this error is being sent by IIS since the request never reaches the controller.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: This article should help: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your customer doesn't want people "guessing" incremental or string IDs in the URL, which is how a lot of insecure web applications get hacked (E.g. Sony) right? It's a slightly-uninformed demand, but well intentioned. I understand your pain.

Would your customer know the difference between a hashed and encrypted ID? Maybe your life could be simpler if you just used salted+hashed IDs, which adds just as much *obfuscation* (not *security*!) to the URL, minus the need to URLEncode the encrypted value.

Ideally, you could get this "encrypted ID" requirement punted in favor of a combination of SSL, an authentication system with page level rights-enforcement, and solid audit trail logging. This is standard web application security stuff.